# Switch to a new viewcontroller after validation from log in server

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller

I am trying to make an app when I use a log in screen and I communicate to a server.
When I connect to the server it returns me a value true if my log in is correct or false if its incorrect.
 
Then I try to make the app to switch in a new UIViewController (after I press the log in button) if only the log in is correct. 
For that I store the value that server returns in a string and compare that with another and implement the UIViewController switch. 
After running my app I get an error

```
:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 

Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/dimitriskoumouras/Library/Application Support/iPhone 

Simulator/6.0/Applications/9E756F03-38C1-453C-A26E-497AA7DDAECA/Administrator.app> (loaded)' 

with name 'FourthViewController.xib''!!
```

Posting some code :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    NSLog(@"EWYFPicOneViewController - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {");
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@" data == %@",string);

    NSString *compare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"true"];

    if ( [compare isEqualToString:string])  {
        UIViewController* FourthViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.view addSubview:FourthViewController.view];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"validation not complete");
}
```

Any thoughts?? (i start to think that maybe my whole logic is wrong)..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: remove.xib from the line  initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController.xib"

Comment: this error shows that your nib file name is wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after parsing...

```
 if ( [compare isEqualToString:string])  {

UIViewController* FourthViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:FourthViewController animated:YES];
```

}

and also use this....

```
  UIViewController* FourthViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [self.view addSubview:FourthViewController.view];
```

Comment: After applying your code error is not occuring but although authentication is correct nothing happens...

Comment: put break point and check out whats wrong with it... Is it going in that condition or not......

Comment: Try to find out if your `FourthViewController` exists or not. Try putting breakpoints to where it is getting initialized. Or put this

Comment: Although it worked earlier now again i am getting the same error... Condition is working good...

Comment: Ok after putting breakpoints the error seems to occur when it xcode tries to load fourthviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

> After running my app i get an error :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'FourthViewController.xib''

xib files are xml nib files and they are compiled into nibs. So your should load `FourthViewController.nib` (or simply remove the extension).

Answer (score 0):

Remove xib from this line  first & then check: initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController.xib"